# Sonarqube Git Hub Plugin

Tags: github, sonarqube, github-api, sonarqube-scan

Having issues with Sonarqube github plugin, and wondering if anyone can help.

Using Git Enterprise, API version 3, SonarQube 6.7.1, SonarScanner 3.0.3.778

I am receiving a -1 HTTP Responce (default) from a call to a **sonar.github.endpoint**

I am trying to achieve git hub pull request based sonar scans and am blocked at this point, error is as follows

```
11:42:00.363 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=11ms
11:42:00.364 INFO: Scanning only changed files
11:42:00.365 INFO: Execute project builders
11:42:00.584 DEBUG: Unable to perform GitHub WS operation
org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://enterprise.github/api/v3/user
        at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:633)
        at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:594)
        at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:272)
        at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:234)
        at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getMyself(GitHub.java:384)
        at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.<init>(GitHub.java:158)
        at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubBuilder.build(GitHubBuilder.java:207)
        at org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestFacade.init(PullRequestFacade.java:88)
        at org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder.build(PullRequestProjectBuilder.java:52)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectBuildersExecutor.execute(ProjectBuildersExecutor.java:52)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.InputModuleHierarchyProvider.provide(InputModuleHierarchyProvider.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:265)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:118)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:133)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:602)
        ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
        ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 83 common frames omitted

11:42:00.586 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:42:00.586 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
11:42:00.586 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:42:00.586 INFO: Total time: 1.919s
11:42:00.624 INFO: Final Memory: 53M/782M
11:42:00.624 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:42:00.624 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:265)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:118)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:133)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.DefaultInputModuleHierarchy
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: Failed to execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder
Caused by: Unable to perform GitHub WS operation: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://enterprise.github.com/api/v3/user
11:42:00.625 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
11:42:00.626 DEBUG: Execution stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Looks like your GitHub enterprise server is using SSL with a custom/self-signed certificate.
The solution is to import the certificate in the truststore of the JVM running the scanner.

Comment: Thank you for the help, for reference for others I had to download crt from my enterprise GitHub, and add it to the sonar-scanner in-built JRE                         e.g.  keytool -import -file /to/location/of/file.crt -alias gitHub -keystore /to_sonar_scanner_home/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-linux/jre/lib/security/cacerts